# The Application XXX has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again

Tags: android

I am new to Android, and I am building an app based on a map. When I tried to launch my app, here comes the error, "The Application AdBaiduMapDemo02 has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again."
Here is what the LogCat said:

```
>03-19 09:40:46.983: D/AndroidRuntime(389): Shutting down VM  
>03-19 09:40:46.983: W/dalvikvm(389): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)  
>03-19 09:40:47.023: E/AndroidRuntime(389): FATAL EXCEPTION: main  
>03-19 09:40:47.023: E/AndroidRuntime(389): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.example.adbaidumapdemo02.AdBaiduMapDemo02: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.adbaidumapdemo02.AdBaiduMapDemo02 in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.adbaidumapdemo02-1.apk]  
>03-19 09:40:47.023: E/AndroidRuntime(389):     at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:466)  
>03-19 09:40:47.023: E/AndroidRuntime(389):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3260)  
>03-19 09:40:47.023: E/AndroidRuntime(389):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:117)  
>03-19 09:40:47.023: E/AndroidRuntime(389):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:969)  
>03-19 09:40:47.023: E/AndroidRuntime(389):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)  
>03-19 09:40:47.023: E/AndroidRuntime(389):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)  
>03-19 09:40:47.023: E/AndroidRuntime(389):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)  
>03-19 09:40:47.023: E/AndroidRuntime(389):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)  
>03-19 09:40:47.023: E/AndroidRuntime(389):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)  
>03-19 09:40:47.023: E/AndroidRuntime(389):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)  
>03-19 09:40:47.023: E/AndroidRuntime(389):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)  
>03-19 09:40:47.023: E/AndroidRuntime(389):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)  
>03-19 09:40:47.023: E/AndroidRuntime(389): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.adbaidumapdemo02.AdBaiduMapDemo02 in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.adbaidumapdemo02-1.apk]  
>03-19 09:40:47.023: E/AndroidRuntime(389):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)  
>03-19 09:40:47.023: E/AndroidRuntime(389):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)  
>03-19 09:40:47.023: E/AndroidRuntime(389):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)  
>03-19 09:40:47.023: E/AndroidRuntime(389):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:942)  
>03-19 09:40:47.023: E/AndroidRuntime(389):     at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:461)  
>03-19 09:40:47.023: E/AndroidRuntime(389):     ... 11 more
```

**My code of MainActivity is as follows:**

```
package com.example.adbaidumapdemo02;  
import com.baidu.mapapi.BMapManager;  
import com.baidu.mapapi.GeoPoint;  
import com.baidu.mapapi.MapActivity;  
import com.baidu.mapapi.MapController;  
import com.baidu.mapapi.MapView;  
import android.os.Bundle;  
public class MainActivity extends MapActivity {  
    BMapManager mBMapMan = null;  
    MapView mMapView = null;  
    @Override  
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  
        mBMapMan = new BMapManager(getApplication());  
        mBMapMan.init("027FB8C5D701284490FF6C80E66AD7EAB37154C4", null);  
        super.initMapActivity(mBMapMan);  
        mMapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.bmapsView);  
        mMapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);  
        MapController mMapController = mMapView.getController();  
        GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int)(39.915 * 1E6), (int)(116.404 * 1E6));  
        mMapController.setCenter(point);  
        mMapController.setZoom(12);  
    }  
    @Override   
    protected void onDestroy() {  
        if(mBMapMan != null)  
        {  
            mBMapMan.destroy();  
            mBMapMan = null;  
        }  
        super.onDestroy();  
    }     
    @Override  
    protected void onPause() {  
        if (mBMapMan != null)  
        {  
            mBMapMan.stop();  
        }  
        super.onPause();  
    }     
    @Override  
    protected void onResume() {  
        if (mBMapMan != null)  
        {   
            mBMapMan.start();  
        }  
        super.onResume();  
    }  
    @Override  
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {  
        return false;  
    }  
}
```

**Is there any idea to fix this? Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere in your project you are referencing a class `AdBaiduMapDemo02` which the Java Class Loader can not find.

I would suggest doing a search in your project for "AdBaiduMapDemo02"

Comment: I find the reference to class _AdBaiduMapDemp02_ in my _Manifest.xml_ document: `  <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        >`. In my _strings.xml_ document, app_name is "AdBaiduMapDemo02". so what should I do next? Thanks.

Comment: As long as in strings.xml you have the following it should be fine:
`<string name="app_name">AdBaiduMapDemo02</string>`

There might be another reference to "AdBaiduMapDemo02" in the manifest.

Comment: I really cannot find another reference to "AdBaiduMapDemo02"......It still cannot work.

Answer (score 1):

> com.example.adbaidumapdemo02.AdBaiduMapDemo02: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:

Where is your AdBaiduMapDemo02.class?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand that. I only have an activity called MainActivity, so there is MainActivity.class in my bin file.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with my Manifest.xml file?    
    `<application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
         >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>`

Comment: Your manifest.xml is correct.Are you test your project on emulator or device?

Comment: On emulator, and the api level is 14.

Comment: Sometime I have got the same problem with you but when i run in device then it's ok. You should try.